# SQL Server query for Total of hours across multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I've tried to resolve this a few ways and wanting some extra help.
I'm wanting to return the same number of rows but trying to calculate the number of total hours delivered by each Employee for each service on each day.
I've added a duplicate flag but that doesn't help me to work out the max hours by the 1 employee in 1 day.

```
Emp Service Date        Start   End     Hrs     Duplicate   Flag    Flag hrs
Fred    xyz 14/09/2017  8:45    15:00   6.25    1          1        6.25
Fred    xyz 14/09/2017  9:00    14:15   5.25    1          0        0
Fred    xyz 14/09/2017  9:00    14:15   5.25    2          0        0
Fred    xyz 14/09/2017  9:00    15:00   6       1          0        0
John    xyz 15/09/2017  10:00   12:00   2       1          1        2
John    xyz 15/09/2017  10:00   13:00   3       1          0        0
John    xyz 15/09/2017  11:00   15:00   4       1          0        0
John    xyz 15/09/2017  12:00   16:00   4       1          1        4
```

the last 2 columns are the ones I can't quite work out how to add.  I've tried Overlaps and other ANDing methods.

thanks,  Dave

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for an OVER clause. Not sure what the duplicate flag is for though? If you ignore your last three columns, assuming they are computed columns in a query, you could use...

```
Select 
*,
sum(Hrs) over (partition by Emp, Date, Service order by Date)
From (select distinct * from your table) x
```

If the last three columns are actual columns in your table just replace select * in the derived table with the column names, except those three.

Comment: He wants service too so its
sum(Hrs) over (partition by Emp, Service,Date order by Date)

Comment: good catch @SEarle1986 I didn't see the service word in the OP

Comment: Thanks for that, it is SQL Server 2016

Comment: I tried the Sum with the partition statement.  This is good to return the total hours across all rows but it doesn't remove the overlap hours across the 4 shifts.       The Duplicate column is used for something else but will allow me to filter out some of the duplicate overlap hours for this requirement.  The last 2 columns in my table are the ones I can't work out to resolve

Comment: What do the last two columns do? See my latest edit.

Comment: The updated select still only sums the hours across the multiple rows.    The last 2 rows of my example output table are not currently in the table but are the columns I want to add.                                                             I want to have the "Flag" column for the unique overlapping hours and the "Flag Hrs" column to represent the total hours less the overlapping hours